# How to backup a primary member of MongoDB Replica Set

Tags: mongodb, backup, sharding

I am working on a backup concept for our MongoDB sharded cluster.

The Config Servers are in a Replica Set of 3 nodes. Here the backup procedures are well documented and I don't have any issue there.

However, the Shards are Replica Sets of only 1 node each, thus every Shard has only the primary.
Availability is not top-priority, our application server will buffer the documents (at least for a certain period) if a shard or even the entire cluster is not available.

I the MongoDB documentation I did not find any tutorial to backup from a primary, i.e. are there any topic I have to consider?

Backup will be done by LVM Snapshot on Linux. I assume `mongodump` is not option here. Documentation says

> mongodump and mongorestore are simple and efficient tools for backing
>   up and restoring small MongoDB deployments, but are not ideal for
>   capturing backups of larger systems.

However, the amount of all data will be around 150 TB - fairly big.

Comment: have you looked at [backup with filesystem snapshots](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/index.html#back-up-with-filesystem-snapshots) in the doc?

Comment: A sharded cluster has some data on each shard.  Getting a point-in-time backup from all shards is difficult.  If you can Quiesce the entire cluster long enough for backups to complete you can get a good point in time backup.  Shard size plays a role in how long backups take.  Say your 150 TB is spread across 150 shards then backup of all 150 shards (each at 1TB assuming good shard key) at the same time would not take much time, but a lot of effort and management.  You may want to look into MongoDB Ops Manager, or Cloud Manager for backup tooling.